# UIWebView load PDF Bytes from NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, uiwebview

I have a webservice which returns PDF bytes as a string. I convert the string to NSData by doing:

```
NSData* bytes = [fileBytes dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I then try to load the bytes into a webview by:

```
 [self.webViewFile loadData:bytes MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
```

But I get the error: "failed to find PDF header: `%PDF' not found."

The beginning of my byte string looks like this when printing to the console: "%PDF-1.6
%\U00e2\U00e3\U00cf\U00d3"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDF files are binary files. They can only rarely be represented as UTF8 encoded strings directly. It's more likely your PDF file is encoded to a UTF8 string using Base64 encoding.

You can create the NSData object directly from the string using

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithBase64EncodedString:fileBytes options:0];
```

Comment: When I use this method, the NSData from the string is null

Comment: The NSData object will be nil if the string passed in can not be decoded using a base64 scheme. You need to know how your data is encoded to decode it.

Comment: This works, thank you. The server was not originally returning the file in a 64 Base encoded string. Once forcing Base 64 on the server, I was able to resolve my issue